# Bash - seamlessly run scripts with CRLF line endings

Tags: windows, bash, docker, newline

I am using VM (in my case simply boot2docker) to run docker containers on Windows host. For convinience, my source files are mapped from host file system, so text files are by default using Windows-style CRLF line endings instead of Unix-style LF endings.

When I try to run some .sh file from docker container, I'll get an error

```
bash: ./script.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

**Is there a way how could I somehow tell bash/sh interpreter to automatically convert \r\n to \n and run a file?**

Sure, I could do some piplelining like this `cat script.sh | tr -d "\r" | sh` or even create an alias for that, but it would not cover situation where one script includes another.

The only acceptable solution I have found so far, is to set Git to checkout source files in UNIX format.

Comment: can you post `echo $TERM` ?

Comment: It is standard docker container, `echo $TERM` returns `dumb`

Comment: try `export TERM=xterm` or `exec >/dev/tty 2>/dev/tty </dev/tty` (tip from https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/728)

Answer (score 19):

You can commit a .gitattributes file in your repo in the root folder to automatically tell Git to apply LF line endings to all .sh files when checking out, even on Windows. This way you or other developers don't have to remember to configure Git on each machine where you clone your repo.

```
# Set line endings to LF, even on Windows. Otherwise, execution within Docker fails.
# See https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/
*.sh text eol=lf
```

Comment: Same in details here: https://techblog.dorogin.com/case-of-windows-line-ending-in-bash-script-7236f056abe

Answer (score 3):

For some scripts the solution `ln -s /bin/bash /bin/bash^M` will fail.
So create a script /bin/bash^M that will dos2unix the arguments they get and run them with `"$@"`.

Edit:
I tried it with the following bash^M script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PROG=$1
shift
dos2unix $PROG > /dev/null 2>&1
$PROG "$@"
```

This will fail when your script includes other scripts with a dot, in that case you should avoid this work-around and go for the Unix format.
You said you can checkout in Unix format, or you can self change the files.
And commit into git, it is an improvement to have unix files stored in git in unix format. When you really want to edit them under windows, change the settings of your editor or dos2unix afterwards.

Comment: This looks like clever approach! So when I create file `/bin/bash^M`, I will get rid of the error `bash: ./script.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`, but I will introduce another error `script.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found`, where line 2 is supposed to be empty line, but interpreter thinks there is a command named `\r.

Comment: That is why your bash^M should not call bash directly, but first dos2unix / tr the script that is to be run.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you could write a script such as

```
#!/bin/bash
#bash_run_unixified
#unixify and run in bash
dos2unix < "$1" | /bin/bash
```

and assuming you saved it in /urs/local/bin/bash_run_unixified with appropriate permissions (`sudo chmod o+r,o+x`), then you could prefix your scripts with

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash_run_unixified
#This script has CRLFs in it
```

If you don't want such unusual shebang lines, you could

```
$ ln -s /usr/local/bin/{bash_run_unixified,bash}
```

and then use
(As Walter A. notes, it might be a good idea to link it to `bash^M` too)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

as your shebang line (`/usr/local/bin/` is normally closer to the beginning of your `$PATH` than `/bin` so the env command should select the `bash` that links to `bash_run_unixified`).

(Word of caution: I haven't tested any of this)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I have is to make sure to use editors (like Notepad++ or Sublime Text) able to save directly with the proper eol style.

That way, I don't have to [`dos2unix`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) any file in my boot2docker session.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get scripts with CRLF line endings to "self-heal" by placing a oneliner as the first line of code in the bash script itself (after the #!/bin/bash line).

The only hitch is that the script needs to be run with "bash script.sh" for it to work (when it has CRLF line-endings) - I have found that most users do this anyway as the first thing when "./script.sh" doesn't work, so this has saved me in most cases.
After the script has fixed itself, and it no longer has CRLF line-endings, executing it with "./script.sh" as normal then works without issue.

Check out my GitHub page for the [oneliner](https://github.com/bundgas/Bash-CRLF-selfheal/blob/main/bash-CRLF-selfheal.sh) (see line 3 in the code) and the [readme](https://github.com/bundgas/Bash-CRLF-selfheal).

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio code is also good at changing the line ending to linux or windows file endings