# Docker and gulp

Tags: docker, gulp, docker-compose

I'm using Windows 7 and have a virtual machine running on boot2docker.

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
web:
    image: nginx
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    volumes:
        - /var/www/docker/nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
        - /var/www/:/var/www/html/
    links:
        - php:php

php:
    build: php
    volumes:
        - /var/www/:/var/www/html/
        - /var/www/docker/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
        - /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    links:
        - db:db

db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
        - "13306:3306"
    volumes:
        - /var/lib/boot2docker/mysql/:/var/lib/mysql/
    environment:
        - MYQSL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
```

**gulpfile.js**:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');

var processors = [
  require('precss'),
  require('autoprefixer')({browsers: ['last 2 versions'] }),
  require('cssnano')
];

gulp.task('postcss', function() {
  gulp.src('gulp/stylesheets/*.css')
    .pipe(postcss(processors))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/stylesheets/'))
});

gulp.task('watch-postcss', function() {
  gulp.watch("gulp/stylesheets/*.css", ["postcss"]);
});
```

I'm trying to run Gulp to compile my CSS files with postcss outside the VM, but it seems to break my output file in my VM's shared folder. For example if I compile this:

```
body {
  background: red;
}
```

I get this in the output file (which is what I want):

```
body{background:red}
```

But if I recompile the postcss stylesheet like that:

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

I get this in my output file:

```
body{background:red}���
```

My local (Windows) file is correctly updated, this bug is only in the file inside the VM's shared folder.

I'm new to Docker and don't know what I am doing wrong. Am I supposed to run Gulp inside the VM? Or inside a container? And if so, how do I install and use Gulp inside my VM/container?

Or maybe I did something wrong in the docker-compose file?

Comment: i guess it happens because of the [line endings](http://www.editpadpro.com/tricklinebreak.html), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603737/bash-seamlessly-run-scripts-with-crlf-line-endings.

Comment: @sobolevn I don't see what you mean... I need to convert my css file to UNIX line breaks ?

Comment: i think so. or to windows, i am not sure about where this bug occures.

Comment: @sobolevn I tried to dos2unix both source and ouput css files but it didn't change anything

Comment: try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos

Comment: @sobolevn Am I supposed to convert from Unix to DOS before or after compiling my css file ?
Plus I get an error when I execute these perl commands : "Can't do inplace edit without backup."

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this issue is caused by nginx. You should add `sendfile off;` to your nginx virtual host config.